# Kivy ListItemButton - How to increase the height of button size?

Tags: python, listview, kivy

I am using ListItemButton in my code. But I am not able to change the size of list item button.
Please someone guide how to change the button size of ListItemButton.

I have tried using 'size_hint_y: None' and 'height: '48dp'' in order to achieve this but still **unsuccessful**.

Below you can see the sample code.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class TestRoot(BoxLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Test.kv

```
#: import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter

TestRoot:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        text: "How to the change the button height of ListItemButton?"
    ListView:
        adapter: ListAdapter(data = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'], cls = ListItemButton)
```

Kivy Question On Listitembutton
[image]

Comment: Attaching an `args_converter` with fixed button heights to the adapter should work. Have you tried it?

Comment: Thank you jligeza for your help. I am able to achieve it using your suggestion.
But still I wanted understand why I was not able achieve using 'size_hint_y' and 'height' properties of ListItemButtonn?

Comment: `<ListItemButton>:
    size: (100, '48dp')` works as well. I don't know why, though.

Comment: You haven't included code how you tried it, so I don't know, but `ListView` will be depreciated in favor of `RecycleView` soon anyway.

Comment: @jligeza
Initially I tried adding the following code in kv file.
`<ListItemButton>: 
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'`
But I was surprised that it didn't work. After trying a lot of things I decided to post this question. 
However now I tried your suggestion and it worked!!!

As you told, I got to know that soon `ListView` will be deprecated while I was searching for the properties in ListView to change the height of button.
Anyway, Thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 2):

You can create in your main.py a class that will be inherited by the ListAdapter, something like:

```
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
....
class TestListItemButton(ListItemButton):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestListItemButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.height = "100dp"
```

And then you alter the adapter to inherit the right class

```
adapter: ListAdapter(data = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'], cls = TestListItemButton)
```

and now you can change the self.height to be any value you want

Answer (score 0):

changing the "size" property instead of just the "height", would do the trick, no clue why, it worked for me any way

that's where I found it in the first place:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kivy-users/e-OhrX6uvSg/sQWcKetzBAAJ